# How to write n! until n = k?

Tags: factorial

I am looking for a more formal way to write n!, until n is equal to k.

Example:

n = 10
k = 5
Answer: 10 * 9 * 8 * 7 * 6 * 5

How would a mathematician write this?

Comment: See [falling (and rising) factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: $\frac{n!}{(k-1)!}$

Comment: Why not just $10!/4!$?

Comment: That can be written as a falling factorial, $10^{\underline 6}$, or as a quotient of factorials $\frac{10!}{4!}$. Of course it can also be written $\prod_{k=5}^{10}k$.

Comment: It can also be written using permutation notation, 10P6.  See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n >.

Comment: Thank you people!